# buttons not showing next to each other on mobile

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am just trying to have two buttons next to each other. I read other posts in Stackoverflow and recommendation was to use LinearLayout. I would like to continue to use Relative Layout. Any way I can fix what is showing in the images?

Eclipse:
[image]

HTC One (mobile):

[image]

and here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/welcomeMessageMain"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/LightSlateGray"
        android:textSize="12pt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newDiscountButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/newDiscountBUttonLabel"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
        android:width="115dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="@string/copyrightMessage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newDiscountButton"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/recentDiscountsButtonLabel"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
        android:width="115dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for helping! :)

New code after TableRow and still not working:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/welcomeMessageMain"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/LightSlateGray"
        android:textSize="12pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="@string/copyrightMessage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newDiscountButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/newDiscountBUttonLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
            android:width="115dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/recentDiscountsButtonLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
            android:width="115dp" />

    </TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can use TableRow and put both button in it.

Comment: Why have you added `TextView` in your layout ? Is there any purpose ? As you have shown two buttons in your screenshot.

Comment: What is your issue ? I guess your layout looks perfect in your device. @spacemonkey

Comment: @GrIsHu not really it hasn't been solved yet

Comment: What is your issue ? I guess your layout looks perfect in your device. @spacemonkey

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/stringtxt1"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stringtxt2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"></Button>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="welcomeMessageMain"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="12pt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newDiscountButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="newDiscountBUttonLabel"
        android:width="115dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="copyrightMessage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newDiscountButton"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="recentDiscountsButtonLabel"
        android:width="115dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this disrupted the whole interface :(

Comment: have you changed the background image?

Comment: Ya I did. And working fine in my system. As you can see I have changed the text and background image.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="10">

        <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="3"/>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will be in the desired format.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="@string/welcomeMessageMain"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/LightSlateGray"
    android:textSize="12pt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newDiscountButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal">
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/newDiscountBUttonLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:width="115dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:text="@string/copyrightMessage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal">
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newDiscountButton"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/recentDiscountsButtonLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:width="115dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `textview2` ther in between.. wht is the purpose if it ? you can place it bottom of the screen to display your `copywright` text

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="@string/welcomeMessageMain"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/LightSlateGray"
    android:textSize="12pt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newDiscountButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/newDiscountBUttonLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:width="115dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/latestDiscountsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newDiscountButton"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonxml"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/recentDiscountsButtonLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:width="115dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to Android IDE right now, but looking at the XML, I see that the buttons have different margins.

On your second button, remove the margin and I think you'll get what you're looking for
`android:layout_marginTop="30dp"`